# How can I match a regex in javascript in one line

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's say i have this string "code 123" and i want to get "123". But sometimes the string is empty or have something else, so my code have to look for errors. So I can write this like:

```
var id = null;
var m = str.match(/code (\d+)/);
if (m && m.length > 1) id = m[1];
if (id) {
   ...
```

So my question is if there's any way I can get this to work with a one line or a more simple/clean code. Something like:

```
var id = str.match(/code (\d+)/)[1];
if (id) {
   ...
```

But this break the code if the string is not found. I also could write a function:

```
function firstMatch(str, search) {
    var m = str.match(search);
    if (m && m.length > 1) return m[1];
    return null;
}
```

and then:

```
var id = firstMatch(str, /code (\d+)/);
if (id) {
   ...
```

But I don't want to include this function in every code I write.

Comment: Something like `var id = (m=str.match(/code (\d+)/)) ? m[1] : "";`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The best answer so far is a comment.  You should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var id = (str.match(/code (\d+)/) || [false,false])[1]`

If `(str.match(/code (\d+)/)` is empty or null, it'll default to `[false,false]`, making [0] and consequently [1], the index you're trying to access, equal to false. Then,

```
if (id) {
  // will not be executed if [1] == false
}
```

If `(str.match(/code (\d+)/)` is **not** null or empty, it'll take precedence, and code within the if statement will be executed and `id` will have the non-empty, non-null value from `(str.match(/code (\d+)/)`

Comment: There's no chance match returns an array with less than two items, or something truthy but not an array?

Answer (score 2):

You may assign the match result to a local variable and if it is not null / undefined, access its first index, else use an empty string, or an array of empty strings - just use what is best for your scenario.

```
var id = (m=str.match(/code (\d+)/)) ? m[1] : "";
```

JS demo:

```js
var res = (m="Some code 55".match(/code (\d+)/)) ? m[1] : "";
console.log(res);
res = (m="No code".match(/code (\d+)/)) ? m[1] : "";
console.log(res);
```

Comment: won't this break on use strict?

Comment: Declare `m` before that if you need to use strict, it will still be a one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var s = "some string";
 var result = (s.indexOf("123") > -1) ? true : false;
```